# show data linked to logged in user and custom database email address

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm new to coding and I need a little help, please

I need logged in user on WordPress(website) linked to my custom DB via email address to show data from my custom DB, like a company, address, etc etc for the logged in user only

I've managed to get the data from the custom DB to display and logged in user info to display too(this part is so i can see logged in info), with the code below

I guess there must be a way of doing this and would I need to have a relationship in DB tying user email and customer email

any help would be much appreciated

thank you for your time

peter

edited

I now get the results from email addresses that are the same in both tables, but I just require the logged in user to be displayed, how can i do that?

```
      <?php

        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `CustomerT`, `wp_users` where `Email` = `wp_users`.`user_email`");
        foreach ( $result as $print )   { ?>

       Customer ID: <?php echo $print->CustomerID; ?> </br>
            Company: <?php echo $print->Company; ?> </br>
               Address: <?php echo $print->Address; ?></br>
                      City: <?php echo $print->City; ?></br>
                 County: <?php echo $print->County; ?></br>
              Postcode: <?php echo $print->Postcode; ?></br>
            First Name: <?php echo $print->FirstName; ?></br>
            Last Name: <?php echo $print->LastName; ?></br>
                    Email: <?php echo $print->Email; ?></br>
             Phone No: <?php echo $print->PhoneNo; ?></br>
<?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user(); ?>

    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
     echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
        echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
        echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
        echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
        echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
        echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
    } 
    else { wp_loginout(); } ?>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `where customerid = 00001` - you sure about that? Leading zeros could be treated as an octal unless quoted. What's the schema and values for this?

Comment: that was just to get 1st record, just to display, i know that part needs changing

Comment: it may of added the leading zeros from when i imported it from ms access to sql using csv file, also renamed the names COL 1 instead of CustomerID COL 2 etc etc, i had it working on ms access but i wanted it all in one place

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking here. Do you need to join 2 database tables to get only the customer's email of the currently logged in user?

Comment: I want to check if logged in user email matches the email in custom DB and only then display their details from custom DB if both match, maybe if no record then display No records found .... does that make sense

Comment: i added this  $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `CustomerT`, `wp_users` where `Email` = `wp_users`.`user_email`"); now i get my two results which have the same email in both tables, but i just need to view the logged in user only

Comment: maybe i'm just looking at it wrong, maybe i just need to first  get current logged in user email and compare it with the email in custom table and display if they match, if no match then display no match, please help......it maybe basic but i'm new

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the other query with this query and it seems to work the way I needed it to

```
SELECT * FROM   `CustomerT`  WHERE  CustomerT.Email  = '$current_user->user_email'
```